# Error 462 in VBA: populate MS Word With Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to populate word content controls using input from a spreadsheet. My code either doesn't work OR consistently work one time out of 2. I get the error 462.

Can someone help me to figure out what the problem is?

Thanks!

```
Private Sub Accept_Click()

Dim directory As String
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
Dim dt As String

Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

directory = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
    .InitialFileName = directory
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select doc letter"
    .Filters.Add "All", "*.*"

    If .Show = True Then
        txtfilename = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

wrdApp.Visible = True
On Error GoTo Handler

'i get error on the next line: 
Set doc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(txtfilename, , False, , , , , , , , , True) 

Documents(txtfilename).Activate

For Each cc In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdPrimaryHeaderStory).ContentControls
    If cc.Tag = "uptitle" Then cc.Range.Text = mill_box.Text
Next

For Each cc In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).ContentControls
    If cc.Tag = "client" Then cc.Range.Text = TextBox1.Text & Chr(10) & TextBox2.Text _
 & ", " & TextBox3 & Chr(10) & TextBox4 & " , " & TextBox5 & Chr(10) & TextBox6
    If cc.Tag = "mill" Then cc.Range.Text = mill_box.Text


Next
ActiveDocument.Windows.Application.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize

Unload Me

ActiveDocument.Activate



Exit Sub
Handler:
Set wrdApp = Nothing
Set doc = Nothing
Unload Me
MsgBox "error"

End Sub
```

Comment: step through the code. What line are you getting error on? What have you tried? There are quite a few hits on that error with VBA and many even specify that it happens every other time.

Comment: Hi Rodger, I mentioned the line where I am getting the error in the code. I indeed went over the blogs about this error. In my case, if the code is not working, i close the excel sheet, and then it works every other time. thanks

Comment: Oh, it is in as a comment. Sorry, I missed that light gray text.

Comment: You are definitely right about it having the full path. Not sure what I was thinking there. Sorry! Is this sub referenced by another or something like that or is it an entity unto itself?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting error!

Reading the info from [this page](https://anictteacher.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/vba-error-462-explained-and-resolved.pdf) (which was Google hit #2 for me on "error 462" - LMGTFY :) ) points to an answer discussed in a [Microsoft knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189618):

- You create a Word Application object through code, and assign it to a variable.
- When you reference any of Word's Application members (like ActiveDocument) without the qualifying Application variable in front of it, VBA creates a hidden variable for it instead.
- All seems fine, since VBA can call Word through both your own variable and the hidden one.
- When you now set your own variables to Nothing, the hidden variable will still be there keeping Word alive.
- When you come around a second time, the implicit hidden variable messes things up.

Your code also accesses `ActiveDocument` and `Documents(txtfilename)` instead of your own `doc` and `wrdApp`.

I do not know if this is a solution to your problem (no time to check it through), but it seems very applicable.

Comment: Thanks Carl for your response, I think that the "hidden variable" is what is causing all the trouble. But at the same time, I installed office 2016 this week and my code just stopped working!! Anyway... I just posted the solution below that solves what I am trying to achieve. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

When it goes through without an error you are unloading Me and then exiting the sub. You don't set wrdApp and doc to Nothing like you do when there is an error. If you fix that logic so those get set to nothing on a successful run does it keep happening?

Comment: txtfilename contains the full path. Plus, I terminate word process before running the code.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of trial and errors, here is the code that finally get things done. Thank you for everyone for taking your time to help me in this matter.

```
Private Sub Accept_Click()

Dim directory As String
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

On Error Resume Next

'this part is not necessary, but end users will know they can't have other word
'docs open when working with this file.  
Set wrdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Set doc = wrdApp.Documents("Welcome letter.docx")
If Error <> 0 Then
    Call Killword
End If

On Error GoTo Error_Handler

Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
directory = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
    .InitialFileName = directory
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select welcome letter"
    .Filters.Add "All", "*.*"

    If .Show = True Then
        txtfilename = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

'here is the thing: i had to instantiate the doc before making wrdapp visible. 
Set doc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(txtfilename, , False, , , , , , , , , True)
  wrdApp.Visible = True
doc.Activate

'from now on I have no choice than to refer to doc (not documents(1) or activedocuments! neither work)
For Each cc In doc.StoryRanges(wdPrimaryHeaderStory).ContentControls
    If cc.Tag = "uptitle" Then cc.Range.Text = mill_box.Text
Next

For Each cc In doc.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).ContentControls
'here goes the code i need to execute on my word document. can be anything.

Next
doc.Windows.Application.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize

Unload Me


Exit Sub

Error_Handler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 429, 91
            Err = 0
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            MsgBox ("An unexpected error has occured." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Error number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Error description: " & Err.Description)
            Resume Next
    End Select


'Set wrdApp = Nothing
'Set doc = Nothing
Unload Me


End Sub
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!  I'd recommend to fully qualify all instances, no matter if the code works without qualifying them or not - it can't hurt and can only help clarify the code and improve it's robustness.  Another lesson learned - also for me, since I didn't know you could do this, but now also know you shouldn't either ;)